# React component dispatching generic payload

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I trying to create a reusable `<Column />` component that displays a list of items which each dispatch a generic payload specified by the caller when clicked.

My column takes an `onItemClick` prop which is a function that dispatches a payload (a Redux action in my actual code). I want my function to be able to accept and dispatch a generic `<PayloadType>`:

```
type ColumnProps<PayloadType> = {
  menuItems: { name: string; id: number }[];
  onItemClick: (payload: PayloadType) => void;
};

const Column = <PayloadType extends {}>(
  props: React.PropsWithChildren<ColumnProps<PayloadType>>
) => {
  const { menuItems, onItemClick } = props;
  const handleButtonClick = (menuItem: MenuItem) => {
    onItemClick({ info: menuItem.name });
    /* 
     Argument of type '{ info: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 
     'PayloadType'.
     '{ info: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'PayloadType', but 
     'PayloadType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'
    */
  };
  return (
    <>
      {menuItems.map((menuItem, index) => (
        <button key={index} onClick={(event) => handleButtonClick(menuItem)}>
          {menuItem.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Using the component:

```
type MenuItem = {
  name: string;
  id: number;
};

const testMenuItems: MenuItem[] = [
  { name: "Vanilla", id: 0 },
  { name: "Strawberry", id: 1 },
  { name: "Chocolate", id: 2 },
  { name: "Cookies & Cream", id: 3 }
];

type ColumnPayload = {
  info: string;
};

export default function App() {
  const columnClickHandler = (payload: ColumnPayload) => {
    console.log(`clicked: ${payload.info}`);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Column<ColumnPayload>
        menuItems={testMenuItems}
        onItemClick={columnClickHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

As seen above, I'm receiving the error:

```
Argument of type '{ info: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PayloadType'.
  '{ info: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'PayloadType', but 'PayloadType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

How can I accept and dispatch a generic payload from my component? I'm fairly new to TypeScript so I'm not sure if I'm missing something or simply approaching the problem completely wrong.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-kalam-tt5u5?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: The error is because you're trying to use a specific payload type `ColumnPayload` *inside* the body of your generic function, where you call `onItemClick({ info: menuItem.name })`;

The error can be fixed in your example by making Column non-generic and fixing it to `ColumnPayload` only. Of course, this probably isn't the solution you're after - can you please modify your example so that it shows the problem caused when we simply make Column non-generic?

Comment: I guess there is no problem if I make Column non-generic, other than the fact that `onItemClick` is now tied to an object with a specific shape of `ColumnPayload`. As you alluded to in your response, my Column component is no longer as reusable, which was the main driver behind my attempt at using generics. Maybe I'm not approaching this the right way but I'm not sure how else to accomplish a reusable component that can call a generic function.

Comment: Maybe you should pass onItemClick in as a prop then.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is `Column` cannot create a specific type without help, its only able to be aware that there is some unknown type.

### Type Intersections

That being said, one way you can achieve your generic callback is simply union the payload type with the menu item.

`type MenuItemWithPayload<TPayload> = MenuItem & Payload`

Then dispatch the callback with the entire menuitem. I provided some example code, notice how that `ColumnMenuItem` is both payload and menuitem type? this allows type inferencing were you no longer need to define the payload type when using the column component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-framework-pu4qe?file=/src/App.tsx.

### Generic payload field

A cleaner alternative might be to allow the menu item to contain a payload field. Which is similar to the union type but uses composition.

`type MenuItem<TPayload = unknown> = { name: string; id: number; payload: TPayload }`

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-currying-g1ynk?file=/src/App.tsx

### Forwarding MenuItem

Finally you can simply forward the menu item in the callback and let the parent component generate the payload it needs.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-surf-ihz96?file=/src/App.tsx